# Iceweasel doesn't open downloads correctly

Tags: firefox, download, vlc, iceweasel

When I try to open a tarball from the downloads directory with [iceweasel](https://wiki.debian.org/Iceweasel) it opens it with the VLC-Player. Can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change the default action in:

`Edit -> Preferences -> Applications`

There should be an entry for tarballs. Either chose a default application, to always be asked, or to download without asking.

Comment: It changed back after restarting iceweasel so it opens tarballs with xarchiver again (without changing anything).

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question: the default settings in `Applications` is what to do when you encounter a file from the web. When opening files you downloaded form the `Downloads` section the default file associations of your desktop environment apply. So you need to change them. Which DE are you running?

Comment: I am running XFCE

Comment: In that case you can either do it from `thunar`: right click, open with, and set the default program to your liking (set checkmark), or it should be in `$HOME/.local/share/applications/defaults.list` or a file in  `/usr/share/applications/` - but I never did this manually so far and neither am running XFCE. Look for the keywords "default programs" and "file extension".